# JQUERY: Combining 2 function using OR operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I combine two function with an operator `OR ( || )`
I would like to combine the 2 ifs statement in the script
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvmail/emeYT/7/) is the fiddle

**HTML**

```
<form name="formName" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="attendant[email]" size="13" value="">  
<input type="text" name="attendant[email]" size="13" value="">
<input type="text" name="attendant[email2]" size="13" value="">
<input type="text" name="attendant[email2]" size="13" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("input:text[name='attendant\\[\email\]']", this).filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
        }).length) {
        window.alert("No member email1 should be empty.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
        if ($("input:text[name='attendant\\[\email2\]']", this).filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
        }).length) {
        window.alert("No member email2 should be empty.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Which functions do you want to combine? I don't think OR is the right thing, that will take the first defined function and execute it. perhaps you want an && AND?

Comment: I have two ifs statement in there I would want to combine into 1. Currently the browser is throwing off 2 alerts.

Comment: just put an else before the second if...? That would be really simple

Comment: For that type of field validation I'd keep the `if` statements separate but rather than using an alert in each I'd have an `errorMessages` string that you append to. Then at the end of the function if `errorMessages` is not an empty string display it in an alert so that all validation errors are displayed in a single alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("input:text[name='attendant\\[\email\]']", this).filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
        }).length) {
        window.alert("No member email1 should be empty.");

        event.preventDefault();
    }
       else if ($("input:text[name='attendant\\[\email2\]']", this).filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
        }).length) {
        window.alert("No member email2 should be empty.");

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This is what you required to do..
Hope it may help u.

Comment: hmmm, that looks like the code version of my comment... just saying!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    var email1Validation = function() {
        if($("input:text[name='attendant\\[\email\]']", this).filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
        }).length) {
            window.alert("No member email1 should be empty.");
            return true;
        }
    },
    email2Validation = function() {
        if ($("input:text[name='attendant\\[\email2\]']", this).filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) == "";
        }).length) {
            window.alert("No member email2 should be empty.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(email1Validation() || email2Validation()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```